# Assessing Presence of Relationship Between 2 Variables across Multiple Experiments

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, predictive-models

I have two time-series variables `x` and `y` and am trying to assess whether `x` influences/has an inter-temporal effect on `y`. I was thinking that I should perhaps be using a distributed lag model as I want to be answering the question "does `x` predict `y`". As noted, I suspect that this could be occurring over many time lags and I don't want to constrain it to looking at just one lag.

I have multiple sets of `x` and `y` (they were obtained from surveys), with different features, such as geographic location, category, wave frequency etc. for each set.

As noted I would like to ultimately assess whether `x` predicts `y`. As there are key differences which mean the "true" distributed lag models will likely be different across the experiments, I was thinking of simply assessing the model fit (adjusted $R^2$) of these models across the various experiments.

In my understanding, a "high" (I'm aware this is subjective) model fit would be suggestive of `x` being predictive of `y`. If the model fit is high across a large proportion of these experiments, it suggests predictiveness in general? Is this not similar logic to that of a meta-analysis performed on journal articles?

Does this seem like a reasonable approach or is there a better model/approach to something like this?

Comment: Please indicate your data or a part of it. Define inter-temporal effect.

Comment: @subhashc.davar x and y are both time series. By inter-temporal I mean I want to check whether x at some time t-x (for x = 1,2,3,...) affects y at time t. Another way of saying it, do x values predict future y values.